# accessing variables declared outside the asp code

Tags: asp-classic

```
<script ID="clientEventHandlersVBS" LANGUAGE="vbscript">

s=pass()
y=s

</script>
<%
session("password")=y
Response.write(session("password"))
Response.write(y)
%>
```

i have this code. but nothing is getting stored inside the session variable neither anything is getting printed. cant i access the variables declared outside the asp code or is their any syntax mistake. any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First of all put

```
<% Option Explicit %>
```

at the top of every .asp page.

You will immediatly see that you are trying to access non declared variabels `s` and `y`.

So of course nothing is stored in the session variables.

Can you not use

```
<%
   s = pass
   y = s
%>
```

and so on ?

What is the purpose of the `<script ...` line if you are using `vbscript` any how ?

Answer (score 0):

As implied by the ID of the script (`clientEventHandlersVBS`) the code contained in there refers to the **client** (the browser, IE in this case since it is the only one that supports VB client-side)

the `<% %>` tags though refer to **server** side ASP code..

These two can never communicate as they happen at different times/computers...